# PHP Subdomain RegEx

Tags: php, regex, subdomain

I have registration form where users can register their accounts with subdomain i.e. .mysite.com

Allowed things are,

```
abc.mysite.com
abc-def.mysite.com
abc123.mysite.com
abc_def.mysite.com
```

Not allowed,

```
http://abc.com.mysite.com
http://abc.mysite.com
www.abc.mysite.com
abc.def.mysite.com
abc.com.mysite.com
```

or any thing which is not a valid subdomain

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Underscores are not a valid char in domains/subdomains.

Comment: 1) what have you tried until now? 2) so you allow dot inside the subdomain names as long as one of the elements that result this way are not com or www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the users are going to input only the subdomain prefix, regexp would be something like

[A-Za-z-_0-9]+

and if do not wish to allow it becoming with www., then:
(?!www.)[A-Za-z0-9-_]+

and if you also do not wish to allow it end with .com, then:
(?!www.)[A-Za-z0-9-_]+(?!.com)